# DirectX Rendering

Tags: c++, directx

So I've created this program to render to a window using DirectX.  It has an `init()` method which requires a `HWND` object so that it can initialize DirectX to the window, and then a `render()` method which is called inside of an infinite-loop, and then finally a `cleanup()` method to release DirectX-objects and devices.  However, DirectX will render a couple of frames of a rotating cube (maybe enough for a half-rotation), and then the screen will go black. Then the cube will come back on, but it is still rotating during the black period.  This continues in an on...off...on...off sort of pattern. Is DirectX maybe not rendering correctly to the window?  What's wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO! There are two great resources that explain how to write a good question: http://sscce.org and [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) - you should read those and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: How are you processing WM_PAINT messages and backgrounds? Possibly they are overwriting your drawing sometimes? Without code though, I can't tell.

Comment: @JohnB I don't have any WM_PAINT messages, nor any backgrounds.  I only clear the screen using the IDirectX3DDevice9::Clear() method just  before using IDirectX3DDevice9::Present() to display the scene to the screen.

Comment: Without some source codes, answering this question is like foretelling from tea leaves...

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I think there is a good chance you need to explicitly implement the handling of the background erase event for your window ([see this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648055(v=vs.85).aspx)), otherwise, the default implementation will kick in and get in your way (sometime erasing what DirectX just rendered as others suggested).

But well, as everybody mentioned already: this is only a little theory, and we would need some code to check this further :-).